# phpMyAdmin configuration

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

- How do I increase phpmyadmin session timeout?
- How do I increase phpmyadmin import file size limit(currently it says Max: 2,048KiB). I tried changing `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: this sounds like one for superuser.com

Comment: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config

Answer (score 42, accepted):

config.inc.php > `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 3600 * 9; // 9 hours`

edit from the link posted by ajreal: [LoginCookieValidity](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#LoginCookieValidity)

for the second question , after changing upload_max_filesize in php.ini did you restart apache ( or whatever webserver you use ) ?

Comment: That can't be the solution. I looked in it and found so far: (Your PHP parameter session.gc_maxlifetime is lower than cookie validity configured in phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login will expire sooner than configured in phpMyAdmin.)

Comment: You must also change the setting `session.gc_maxlifetime` in php.ini to be greater than or equal to the value in the answer above.

Comment: Rather than setting this in the php.ini file, better to add the following to your config.inc.php file (typically in the /etc/phpmyadmin directory): ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '86400'); That way you don't compromise security for other PHP scripts, or cause excessive clutter in the RAM due to infrequent Garbage Collection.

Answer (score 14):

**How to set phpMyAdmin default 1440 second timeout higher:**

1. locate php.ini

   ```
   el@apollo:/var/lib/phpmyadmin$ locate php.ini
   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
   ```
2. open the file as root to edit, find this line:

   ```
   session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
   ```
3. Change it to this (500000 seconds is 5.7 days)

   ```
   session.gc_maxlifetime = 500000
   ```
4. Restart apache.

Doing this decreases security because then it increases opportunity for cross site scripting and man in the middle attacks.  It's all fun and games until you find your server is part of a botnet farming for credit cards.

Comment: Rather than setting this in the php.ini file, better to add the following to your config.inc.php file (typically in the /etc/phpmyadmin directory):

    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '86400');

That way you don't compromise security for other PHP scripts, or cause excessive clutter in the RAM due to infrequent Garbage Collection.

Comment: what I read - it wont work. Script with shortest session.gc_maxlifetime will do garbage collection and will remove all the other too.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than setting **session.gc_maxlifetime** in the **php.ini** file, better to add the following to your **config.inc.php** file (typically in the */etc/phpmyadmin* directory):

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '86400');
```

That way you don't compromise security for other PHP scripts, or cause excessive clutter in the RAM due to infrequent Garbage Collection.

Comment: I think this asnwer must be accepted. My current config.inc.php: `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 3600 * 8; ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600 * 8);`

Answer (score 6):

1. Edit phpMyAdmin's `config.inc.php` and add or update `LoginCookieValidity` the value as follows:

   ```
   $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 3600 * 9; // 9 hours
   ```
2. To upload more than 2M:

   ```
   cd /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

   sudo nano php.ini
   ```
3. Search for `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`, and change value to `64M` (for 64 Mb):

   ```
   upload_max_filesize = 64M
   ```
4. Save and exit.
5. Restart `apache`:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```
6. Finish!

Answer (score 6):

For the first question, you need to change the `$cfg[‘LoginCookieValidity’]` config in the config.inc.php.
Open config.inc.php in the phpMyAdmin “root” directory. Look for a line that contains this: $cfg[‘LoginCookieValidity’]. Set the value to the desired amount of seconds. If the line doesn't exist, just add it like this:

```
$cfg[‘LoginCookieValidity’] = 3600; //(3600 = one hour)
```

You will need to login again to phpmyadmin.

This also assumes that the PHP session garbage collection is set-up accordingly. This can be done in a number of ways:

- php.ini; add a line (or change an existing) that contains `session.gc_maxlifetime = <seconds>`
- Apache configuration; add a line to the appropriate  block that says `php_admin_value session.gc_maxlifetime <seconds>`
- config.inc.php (phpMyAdmin); after the previously edited line, add a line with `ini_set(‘session.gc_maxlifetime’, <seconds>);`

About the second question:

You need to change both, `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini.
The `post_max_size` value needs to be at least the `upload_max_filesize` value.

Don't forget to restart your server

[Reference](http://www.joho.se/2011/11/07/increasing-the-phpmyadmin-session-timeout/)

Comment: upvoting for mentioning `post_max_size` as well :)

Comment: Rather than setting this in the php.ini file, better to add the following to your config.inc.php file (typically in the /etc/phpmyadmin directory):

    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '86400');

That way you don't compromise security for other PHP scripts, or cause excessive clutter in the RAM due to infrequent Garbage Collection.

Answer (score 2):

Try by changing `post_max_size` in `/etc/php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

I add to Poelinca's answer that the mechanism of this limit can be found in the PMA sources under `libraries/Config.class.php`,

`function checkUploadSize()`

It will use `upload_max_filesize` if defined or 5M else and if `max_upload_size` is also defined it will get the min of the two.

(PMA version 3.3.7deb7)

Answer (score 0):

> If you wished to keep phpMyAdmin from timing out so often, you might
>   add this line:
>
> $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 86400;
>
> By default, phpMyAdmin times out every 1440 seconds; to change this,
>   change the session.gc_maxlifetime in php.ini as follows:
>
> session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400

https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/phpMyAdmin_configuration_file

Comment: Rather than setting this in the php.ini file, better to add the following to your config.inc.php file (typically in the /etc/phpmyadmin directory): ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '86400'); That way you don't compromise security for other PHP scripts, or cause excessive clutter in the RAM due to infrequent Garbage Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Edit phpMyAdmin's `config.inc.php` and add or update `LoginCookieValidity` the value as follows:

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 3600 * 9; // 9 hours
```

In wamp or xampp or anything you use at `php.ini`,
Search for `upload_max_filesize` this is where you should change it,

we suggest you not use more than 64M filesize cause sometimes it makes crash:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Save and exit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this post has been answered, but I've just resolved the same issue, so I thought I would add my findings to help others.

I needed to increase the PhpMyAdmin upload file size limit from default the 2,048KiB and I too changed the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size and memory_limit, but nothing changed.

It took my a while to find the problem, when I used the phpinfo(); script to identify where the PHP.ini file was it said was here: C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.5\php.ini, but I finally noticed in the PhpMyAdmin homepage that the Web server was running version: 5.6.31.  So, I updated the upload, post and memory limits in the PHP.ini for both versions 5.5 and 5.6 and the import limit in PhpMyAdmin increased.